# jQuery draggable + toggleClass problem

Tags: jquery, css

the problem here is that the toggleClass position top:0px; left:0px will not trigger.. only the width and height and background-color will activate.. it will work if i will not drag the div(draggable).. if i start to drag the element, the toggled class positioning will not effect.. i dont know if there's such a function in jquery to help this..

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#x").draggable().dblclick(function(){
                $(this).toggleClass("hi");
            });
        });
    </script>        
    <style>
        .hello {
            background:red;
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            position:relative;
            top:100px;
            left:100px;
        }

        .hi {
            background:yellow;
            position:relative;
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="x" class="hello">

    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The draggable stuff is interfering with your positioning. Draggable will assign specific `left` and `top` CSS via a `style` attribute as you drag the the `<div>` around, `style` attributes override the values that come from the `class` attribute. You can get around this by using `!important`:

```
.hi {
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 0px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
}
```

Of course, the `<div>` will cease to be draggable once the `hi` class is added as the `!important` positions will override what the draggable is trying to do.

I'd recommend that you get yourself a WebKit browser (such as Chrome or Safari) for testing and debugging, WebKit's "inspect element" is awesome and better than anything else I've come across for sorting out HTML/CSS issues.